# how to run complete test suite with multiple data?

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio, test-suite, test-data, katalon-recorder

How to run complete test suite with multiple data ?

While am trying to do it is running complete test suite but the multiple test data is called for one test case after finishing it calling the next test case in the suite... Please let me know how to run complete test suite with multiple data set in katalon studio version 7.

Comment: Could you put some screenshot of your test suite ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to combine [multiple data sources](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/combine-multiple-data-sources.html#test-data) in Katalon 7:

1. In the Test Data table, click Add to add data file(s).
2. In Test Data Browser, select a combination of data files you prefer to use for variable binding. The selected test data files are added to the table accordingly.
3. Double-click on the Data Iteration to specify the data range to be used for execution.
4. Click Type to toggle between One and Many, which represents the test data relationship of multiple test data sources.

**BUT**, it is not possible in the free version (see [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/ks7-any-limitations-on-data-driven-testing) and [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/katalon-7-combining-multiple-data-sources-is-only-available-on-katalon-studio-enterprise-version)). The free version supports only one data set per test case.

Comment: Thanks, am using a free version of katalon studio.